# JavaScript Style & Clunky Syntax & Design

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, filter, functional-programming

Which of these functions written in JavaScript is superior and why?

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  var filtered_messages = messages.filter(function(message) {
    if (message.message.length < 50){
     return message.message;
    }
});
  var short_messages = filtered_messages.map(function(message){
    return message.message;
  });
  return short_messages;
}
//My solution
```

Using the Array.prototype.filter() method in JavaScript to iterate over an array and only keep the messages which are less than 50 characters. The messages are objects and you can call .message on a message-item. I think my code has side affects and is not very DRY.

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  return messages.filter(function(item) {
    return item.message.length < 50 }).map(function(item) {
      return item.message;
    });
}
// This is the other solution.
```

Basically I understand this method, it seems more complex and obfuscated. Maybe more abstract. I also do not like the syntax "}).map(". As I think this is clunky.

Comment: It depends on how you indent it, you can write the later in a different form, and use short variables and it becomes more readable IMO http://dpaste.com/2BBZV68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to couple the actual message extraction logic, the testing logic to see if your message is short and the logic to retrieve short messages into one function? If it was me, I would probably write three functions like this

```
function isShortMessage(messageText) {
   return messageText && messageText.length < 50;
}

function extractMessageText(message) {
  return message && message.message;
}

function getShortMessages(messages) {
   return messages.map(extractMessageText).filter(isShortMessage);
}
```

Of course, if you wanted `message` objects to be returned, you could modify your `isShortMessage` function to operate on actual message objects instead of just the text but you get the general idea.